# The unnamed constructor is already defined

Tags: json, flutter, dart, model, flutter-test

I created a *Post Model* class using Dart and got this error saying `"message": "The unnamed constructor is already defined.\nTry giving one of the constructors a name"`. Thsi is how my code is below:

```
  final String caption;
  final String comments;
  final String datePosted;
  final int likes;

  Post({
    required this.caption,
    required this.comments,
    required this.datePosted,
    required this.likes,
  });

  factory Post(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      caption: json['Caption'],
      comments: json['Comments'],
      datePosted: json['Date Posted'],
      likes: json['Likes'],
    );
  }
}
```

Please help I'd really appreciate it

Comment: Dart does not support method overloading, so the constructors are required to have different names. You can create a named constructor like `Post.nameOfConstructor()`.

Answer (score 1):

change to this

```
  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      caption: json['Caption'],
      comments: json['Comments'],
      datePosted: json['Date Posted'],
      likes: json['Likes'],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks man I kinda forgot the .fromJson

Comment: yeah, your welcome, can you tick check correct